# Unable to get filtering to work in combo box

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, carbon-design-system

From this link: https://carbon-svelte.vercel.app/components/ComboBox there is a piece of code that should allow me to enable fitering in a ComboBox component.

```
<script>
  import { ComboBox } from "carbon-components-svelte";

  function shouldFilterItem(item, value) {
    if (!value) return true;
    return item.text.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
  }
</script>

<ComboBox
  titleText="Contact"
  placeholder="Select contact method"
  items={[{ id: '0', text: 'Slack' }, { id: '1', text: 'Email' }, { id: '2', text: 'Fax' }]}
  {shouldFilterItem}
/>
```

In my project I did a copy past of the function and the component is added as follow:

```
<ComboBox
    titleText="Currency"
    items={currencyListCarbon}
    bind:value={unitCurrency}
    shouldFilterItem}
/>
```

currencyListCarbon is the list of currencies. These appear all in the combo box, but since I have over 100, I do not want to scroll when I can simply type USD and it will filter for me, allowing me to select the proper value.
I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: description is not defined

This is due to item being undefined, but I cannot figure out why it is undefined when the combobox has all the items.
These are loaded during page load from database.

I've tried to change the function to check for undefined. Added console.log to see the values of item and value and pretty much item is always undefined.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your `shouldFilterItem` function body and the currencyListCarbon example?

Comment: shouldFilterItem is a copy paste from the original. It is already in the question. the content of currencyListCarbon is 
0: {id: "AED", description: "United Arab Emirates Dirham"}
1: {id: "AFN", description: "Afghan Afghani"}
2: {id: "ALL", description: "Albanian Lek"}
3: {id: "AMD", description: "Armenian Dram"}
4: {id: "ANG", description: "Netherlands Antillean Guilder"}
5: {id: "AOA", description: "Angolan Kwanza"}
6: {id: "ARS", description: "Argentine Peso"}
7: {id: "AUD", description: "Australian Dollar"}
....

Comment: and solved it based on your question. Got it what I was doing wrong. I had to change to item.id instead of item.text. Misunderstoof what item.text was supposed to be.